# Component rendering on all routes-react router V3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, immutable.js

I am trying to create some nested routes with some parameters and have a certain component render on a certain route. I am mapping through the data to and using conditional rendering to single out the one item, but the component is still rendering on all routes.

In the following snippet I am (what I think I am doing) mapping over my data and saying that if the name is `shifts` then render the specific component, else `null`. The component is in fact rendering, but it is rendering on all my routes in this data structure. Any reason why it is not solely appearing when clicking on `shifts` and vanishing when clicking on the other routes? Any help would be awesome.

```js
import React from 'react';

import { schedulingData } from '../../../../data/data';
import ShiftsView from './ShiftsView';

class SchedulingChildItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{this.props.params.schedulingChild}</h2>
        {
          schedulingData.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <div key={index}>
                {
                  item.get('categories').map((category) => {
                    return (
                      <div key={category.get('name')}>
                        {
                          category.get('subcategories').map((subcategory) => {
                            return (
                              <div key={subcategory.get('name')}>
                                {
                                  subcategory.get('name') === 'Shifts'
                                    ? <ShiftsView />
                                    : null
                                }
                              </div>
                            );
                          })
                        }
                      </div>
                    );
                  })
                }
              </div>
            );
          })
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default SchedulingChildItem;
```

Here is the data:

```js
export const schedulingData = Immutable.fromJS([
  {
    value: 'scheduling',
    title: 'Scheduling',
    route: '/scheduling',
    name: 'calendar',
    categories: [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: 'Your Schedule',
        subcategories: [
          {
            id: 0,
            name: 'Shifts',
            route: '/scheduling/shifts',
          },
          {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Make Requests',
            route: '/scheduling/makeRequests',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Reports',
        subcategories: [
          {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Coming Soon!',
            route: '/scheduling/comingSoon',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Manage',
        subcategories: [
          {
            id: 2,
            name: 'By Day',
            route: '/scheduling/byDay',
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            name: 'By Week',
            route: '/scheduling/byWeek',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

and here are my routes:

```js
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={ShellNavigation} >
      <IndexRoute component={Dashboard} />
      <Route path="/scheduling">
        <Route path=":schedulingChild" component={SchedulingChildItem} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

Component with Link:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

import { schedulingData } from '../../../../data/data';

class Scheduling extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {
            schedulingData.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <div key={index}>
                  {
                    item.get('categories').map((category, c) => {
                      return (
                        <div key={c}>
                          <div>{category.get('name')}</div>
                          {
                            category.get('subcategories').map((subcategory, sc) => {
                              return (
                                <div key={sc}>
                                  {
                                    <Link to={subcategory.get('route')}>{subcategory.get('name')}</Link>
                                  }
                                </div>
                              );
                            })
                          }
                        </div>
                      );
                    })
                  }
                </div>
              );
            })
          }
        </ul>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Scheduling;
```

Comment: Where do you have an `onClick` event or a `Link` element from `react router` to respond to changes?

Comment: @Dez in a `Scheduling` component that pulls in the `SchedulingChildItem` component. I added the snippet of it to the original post.

Comment: @Dez I can add a codesandbox if needed

Comment: easy test, instead of using a ternary to display a component or null, just display `subcategory.get('name')` and make sure it is what you think it is. if it's correct but somehow the ternary is wrong then the problem is somewhere else

Comment: I actually think I got it. Instead of mapping over the data, I did `{ this.props.params.schedulingChild === 'shifts' ? <ShiftsView /> : null }` and that seemed to work. What do you think of this solution? 

Thanks for your help.